# extjs 4.2.1 - Toolbar and delegating click events to buttons

Tags: javascript, html, css, button, extjs

I searched on Google but did not find any answers to this problem...

I have a toolbar that has multiple buttons inside.  How would I go about delegating the click event to each of the buttons inside the toolbar without having to write something like:

```
{
    xtype: 'button',
    text: 'Click me',
    handler: function() {
        // do something...
    }
}
```

for each button?

Comment: I am not.  My plan is to have the Toolbar function a bit like TabPanel, so all I need to do is switch between different panels.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per your comments, I would do something like this:

```
Ext.define('MyContainer', {
    extend: 'Ext.container.Container',

    initComponent: function() {
        var handler = this.handleButton;
        this.defaultType = 'button';
        this.items = [{
            text: 'A',
            key: 'itemA',
            handler: handler
        }, {
            text: 'B',
            key: 'itemB',
            handler: handler
        }, {
            text: 'C',
            key: 'itemC',
            handler: handler
        }, {
            text: 'D',
            key: 'itemD',
            handler: handler
        }];
        this.callParent();
    },

    handleButton: function(btn) {
        console.log(btn.key);
        // do something with key
    }
});

Ext.onReady(function() {

    new MyContainer({
        renderTo: document.body
    });

});
```

Comment: I ended up using MVC :\  But thanks anyways.  I think this will come in handy later on.

Comment: The approach is still somewhat similar.